# What changed in the consensus mechanism in Luban Update of BNB Smart Chain?

Tags: binance-smart-chain

I am trying to validate the BNB SmartChain blocks and after the last update in the testnet of the chain, the signature of the blocks are not being validated. I can see the `Extra Data` field is much bigger. In the previous version, the signer of the block, extracted from the block signature was also the validator of the block and was included in the validator list but now the signer of the block is not included in the validator list of the block.